Shrink/fatten does not work

Here I am using a boolean on my subject with two cylinders and then duplicating the cylinders and shrinking them, one is working but the other one is not.


Hello, are you sure that this is a linked duplication? (Alt D)

I'm not sure what the OP means. Maybe they should describe the problem more in detail?

We do need more information, here.. what is the relationship of the 2 cylinders (instances? Part of one object?) perhaps a share on https://blend-exchange.com/ would save unnecessary discussion of details.

Robin Betts,  i make a cylinder and then use array modifier so both cylinder should part of one i guess

You have 2 different boolean objects here: Cylinder, which is only seen as a Bound box, and Cylinder.001 that you see as Solid. The object that is booleaned doesn't use Cylinder.001 as boolean object, so you can edit it as much as you want, it won't change the shapes of the wholes.


but i cant shrink cylinder 1 that i can see as solid . can you please try to shrink the cylinder one and make small you can see the problem i hope

it works for me, it reduces the size of the cylinder and the arrayed cylinders, for a cylinder shrink/fatten won't be different than scale
